# Export from sql to excel

Tags: sql, excel, csv, export-to-excel, sqlplus

I run a query using sqlplus command line interface. The query will fetch some 30 million records. I need to export the result to either csv or xls format. Can anyone let me know if this is possible?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know whether your tool will allow you to create a 30M row Excel file but [2010 is still limited to 1M rows](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2010/thread/ef8eaae1-8215-4f78-8333-7325319c4d68) at least for Excel to *use* it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `spool myresults.csv` before your select statement, which Excel can easily open.

#### EDIT

Like this:

```sql
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET COLSEP ','
--That's the separator used by excel later to parse the data to columns
SET LINES 100 PAGES 100
SET FEEDBACK off
--If you don't want column headings in CSV file
SET HEADING off 
Spool ~\myresults.csv
--Now the actual query
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;
Spool OFF
```

#### EDIT 2

You might want to batch your results if you're going to query 30M records. I've never gone that far in an excel file but the limit is 65535 rows (that would be 458 files for 30M records).

I'd go with cutting up your query into block of 60K blocks and spooling each select to a different excel file, maybe by looping on an integer and concatenating it to the end of each filename.

Comment: Since 2007+, Excel sheets have 1 048 576 rows.

Comment: True, I'm so used to work with 2003 and create reports that use 2003 that I overlooked that. He'll still have 30+ files to work with if he cuts it up­.

Comment: That will not work properly if values themselves contain comas.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SET NUM 24
SPOOL sample.xls
SELECT * from users;
SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF
```

This option will help you to export directly to a excel file

Comment: Actually this exports to a HTML file that contains a TABLE element. Excel can load this file and import it correctly. The advantage to [EplusL's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11831315/822870) is that commas and other "weird" characters are handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET PAGESIZE 40000

SET FEEDBACK OFF

SET MARKUP HTML ON

SET NUM 24

SPOOL file_name.xls

---- Execute your query

SPOOL OFF

SET MARKUP HTML OFF

SPOOL OFF
```

[Spool sqlplus to xls format](https://www.orahow.com/2015/09/spool-sqlplus-output-to-excel-format.html)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value