# sql oracle query data export

Tags: sql, database, export-to-excel

is it possible to export the data from a query using a script alone? i like to run the query and have the data exported automatically without the manual process of exporting the data into .cvs.

I've tried SPOOL but it doesn't export the fetched data, just the code itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See below  , replace table> with your table name and conditions> with your where conditions

```
set colsep '|'
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep off

spool output.dat

select '|', <table>.*, '|'
  from <table>
where <conditions>

spool off
```

Comment: It still doesnt do anything different, it just prints the query and not the data.

Comment: This is what I had used before for testing: 
SPOOL C:\Users\VM\Desktop\QueryExport\data.csv
SELCT * FROM DESK.DEPT

Comment: I am using Oracle Sql Dev and have already followed this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831254/export-from-sql-to-excel

Comment: Looks like your problem is with the query ,do you ge any result? Do you see any result on the sqlplus consol ?